# Find all cookies with Scrapy

Tags: python, cookies, scrapy, web-crawler

I making a web crawler with Scrapy which will visit a list of URLs and return all cookies from these domains including those set by third parties.

This spider follows all links on the given URLs and writes each cookie in a separate text file:

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
import requests

class MyItem(Item):
    url= Field()


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "a"
    start_urls = ['http://www.dailymail.co.uk/home/index.html']

rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_url', follow=False), )

def parse_url(self, response):
    item = MyItem()
    item['url'] = response.url
    filename = '%s.txt'
    if response.headers.getlist('Set-Cookie'):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]       
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            for cookie in response.headers.getlist('Set-Cookie'):
                f.write(cookie)
```

This results in 11 different text files each containing a cookie. The result is inconsistent with that produced by the website cookie-checker.com.

Is there a way to find all cookies set on a page using Scrapy?

Answer (score 0):

Some cookies could be set via client-side(Javascript)
I suggest you use Selenium + PhantomJS to collect all client/server side cookies.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('http://www.example.com/')

cookies = driver.get_cookies()
```